# Java - Custom sort arrays as if they were tuples

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, tuples

Suppose I have three arrays like such:

```
a = [1, 2, 1, 4, 1]
b = [6, 1, 2, 4, 3]
c = [9, 6, 4, 7, 8]
```

I'd like to sort them as if they were a tuple (a, b, c) so the result should look like:

```
a    |    b    |    c
----------------------
1         2         4
1         3         8
1         6         9
2         1         6
4         4         7
```

I'd like to write Java code that does this in the most efficient way possible. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, do you have any code that you have tried so far?

Comment: What is your criteria for sorting?

Comment: How about making a single array of tuples, then sorting it? You know, use the features of the Object-Oriented Language that Java is, and create *objects*. Parallel arrays is an anti-pattern, you shouldn't have them. *[Anti-pattern: parallel collections](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/) by Jon Skeet.*

Comment: I'm simply using it for testing, so the style isn't necessarily required at the moment

Answer (score 2):

You should create a wrapper object implementing `Comparable` interface, map the values in the arrays to the instances of this wrapper class, sort, and use the values.

Example:

```
    static class X implements Comparable<X> {
        final int a;
        final int b;
        final int c;
        public X(int a, int b, int c) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
        }
        
        public int getA() {return a;}
        public int getB() {return b;}
        public int getC() {return c;}
        
        @Override
        public int compareTo(X that) {
            int cmp = Integer.compare(this.a, that.a);
            if (cmp == 0) {
                cmp = Integer.compare(this.b, that.b);
                if (cmp == 0) {
                    cmp = Integer.compare(this.c, that.c);
                }
            }
            return cmp;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] a = {1, 2, 1, 4, 1};
        int[] b = {6, 1, 2, 4, 3};
        int[] c = {9, 6, 4, 7, 8};
        
        IntStream.range(0, a.length)
                 .mapToObj(i -> new X(a[i], b[i], c[i]))
                 .sorted()
                 .forEach(x -> {
                     System.out.printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t\n", x.getA(), x.getB(), x.getC()); 
                 });
    }
```

This code prints expected output:

```
1   2   4   
1   3   8   
1   6   9   
2   1   6   
4   4   7
```

If needed, you can set the sorted values back to the initial arrays.

**Update**
You may also use improved version of the [solution offered by Gerold Boser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62963171/13279831) though it has certain limitations on the range of the input integers and/or the count of the arrays:

```
static int m = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // range of integer values for 3 arrays is -2^20 ... 2^20 -1
    // or 0..2^21 -1
    final int[] a = { Integer.MAX_VALUE>>11, 1, 1, -4, Integer.MIN_VALUE/(1<<11) };
    final int[] b = { 6, 1, 1, 4, 3 };
    final int[] c = { 9, -6, -24, 7, 8 };

    IntSummaryStatistics stats = 
        Stream.of(Arrays.stream(a), Arrays.stream(b), Arrays.stream(c))
              .flatMapToInt(s -> s)
              .summaryStatistics();
    long min = stats.getMin();
    long max = stats.getMax() - min + 1;

    IntStream.range( 0, a.length )
             // use long to fit multiplication results into 63 bits
             .mapToLong( i -> (a[i] - min) * max * max + (b[i]-min) * max + (c[i]-min) )
             .sorted()
             .forEach( n -> {
                 // re-calculate long back to ints
                 a[m] = (int) (n / (max * max) % max + min);
                 b[m] = (int) (n / max % max + min);
                 c[m] = (int) (n % max + min);
                 System.out.printf("% 9d\t% d\t% d\t\n", a[m], b[m], c[m]);
                 m++;
             });
}
```

Output:

```
 -1048576    3   8  
       -4    4   7  
        1    1  -24 
        1    1  -6  
  1048575    6   9
```

***Note** The mentioned limitations may be overcome by using `BigDecimal` instead of `long` to avoid overflow when performing multiplication*

Answer (score 1):

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHNboMwEITP5ClGkSJBQ9ykrfojlEo99NBDTzlGORhDiFMwCDuRIsSz07WhUdS0l9V65vMaZvf8yGdllap98tXJoiprA224kQJ7sljOVcZWJ23SgpUHE41GA@Tcg5E5e6trftLRtaFNnfKCfSizch1drg5xTqNFzrXGJ5cKTecN70llIInxBmiQj6VMUBDqYysVz0HDpMrWG/A60wjQ0BWvt2iE1bFEg0WIu9DWB6poo19Q7KDHcOAIur@GhINeQssR8RTi2UJEnX@K1ZRQ6mMegtJKVWZ2CAjwWMErHxKzV/C13OAGi/kcU8Q/B@qF7XtaU3Zp4veHbVm/c7Hzoez1xmqeG7Ik5dYNmlCNnBFfGhc6DZ9Oe@cstgjc59MqWUUxmq2PMV9O9ETFrgqq49Ci/VqZKfu8fYo1@NuI/zMEbYfe89qu7b4B)

```java
import static java.lang.System.out;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class SO62961100 {

    static int i;

    public static void main( final String[] args ) {

        final int[] a = { 1, 2, 1, 4, 1 };
        final int[] b = { 6, 1, 2, 4, 3 };
        final int[] c = { 9, 6, 4, 7, 8 };

        IntStream.range( 0, a.length )
                .map( i -> a[i] * 100 + b[i] * 10 + c[i] )
                .sorted()
                .forEach( n -> {
                    a[i] = n / 100 % 10;
                    b[i] = n / 10 % 10;
                    c[i++] = n % 10;
                } );
        
        out.printf( "a=%s%nb=%s%nc=%s",
                Arrays.toString( a ),
                Arrays.toString( b ),
                Arrays.toString( c ) );
    }
}
```

### Output

```
a=[1, 1, 1, 2, 4]
b=[2, 3, 6, 1, 4]
c=[4, 8, 9, 6, 7]
```

Comment: It is an interesting implementation but it seems to be very sensitive to the input data.  If any input array contains negative value the calculations will be corrupted.  Also, if max value (instead of hardcoded 10) is detected beforehand, multiplication may result in integer overflow.